# Can the build folder created by "react-scripts build" be ported to another machine/OS without issues?

Tags: build, portability, react-scripts

I'm working on a web app that will be deployed on a raspberry pi (Bullseye 5.15.32), but I can't usually access the raspberry pi itself to build the app.

So far I've been developing and building (using `yarn` with the default `package.json` configuration) in WSL Ubuntu (20.04) and copying the resulting build folder to the raspberry pi, which *seems* to work, but I'd like to know whether the build folder is indeed portable and contains everything it needs to be `served` on any system or I've been lucky and problems could arise down the line due to doing it this way.